# Creating a specific tileable pattern mask

Tags: texturing, materials

[image: The pattern]

I am trying to create a tileable mask for the pattern above.
I tried to arrange the lines with an *Voronoi Texture*, with 0.0 randomness and *Chebychev Distance Matrix* as well as an *Color Ramp* to get hard lines: [image: Node setup]

Like this and with *Vector Math Nodes* like *Add* and *Multiply* and finally *Mix Color Nodes* I tried to arrange the lines, but even after many attempts, I just did not get it tileable, like in the first picture above.

Now I'm out of ideas, how to achieve that. Does somebody has an idea?

Here is what I got so far: [image]

Comment: Why do you want to use a Voronoi texture here?

Comment: I just want to get the result. The Voronoi gives me lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use generate texture coordinates instead of object.

[image]

From that, use some value to determinate the subdivision scale, modulo and scale the coordinates from it.

Then use 'vector absolute' node as the figure is symmetrical in both X and Y.

Next:

[image]

From top to bottom:

Big diagonals are where X equal Y.

Inclined smaller diagonals are where 2 X equal Y.

Shifted lines parallel to the previous where 2 (X - 0.25) equal Y.

Centered horizontal lines are where Y equal 0 but for X less than 0.25.

Bottom/top horizontal lines are where Y equal 0.5 for X greater than 0.25.

Vertical lines are for X equal 0 or 0.5.

[image] (Blender 4.0)

I realized you may effectively want to use object coordinates in order to have a regular wallpaper whatever the object is.

To do that with the previous settings, modify the begining like so:

[image]

Scale down the coordinates with some factor (e.g. 1/64) and get absolute value. The next steps are the same as before.

Comment: A million thanks. I see I am far away from even being a noob in Blender :-D

Comment: This setup won't stretch 1x2 by itself: if you want that, you'll need to divide to half Y at some step

Comment: Ok. First I need to analyze the node tree. I am really eager to understand it completely. I was to naive in thinking craeting patterns would be an easy task.